# java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Tags: java, servlets

Estoy empezando con Java Servlets haciendo un programa con un login. Me corre bien pero a la hora de darle clic al botón Login me aparece este error

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
>     java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
>     java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
>     servlets.Login.doPost(Login.java:57)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Sé que tiene que ver con la línea 57 pero no logro entender qué esta mal. Este es el código del servlet login

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    int n= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Cedula"));
    String p=request.getParameter("Contraseña");

    if(metodos.Validate.checkUser(n, p)) {
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome");
        rd.forward(request,response);
    } else {
        out.print("Sorry username or password error");
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
        rd.include(request,response);
    }

    out.close();
}
```

Este es el del método `checkuser`

```
public static boolean checkUser(int Cedula,String Contraseña) {
    boolean existe=false;
    try {
        Conexion db=new Conexion();
        Connection cn=db.Conectar();
        Statement st=cn.createStatement();
        PreparedStatement ps =cn.prepareStatement("select * from CLIENTE where Cedula=? and Contraseña=?");

        String cedula = String.valueOf(Cedula);
        ps.setString(1, cedula);
        ps.setString(2, Contraseña);
        ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()) {
            existe = true;
            /*
            this.identificacion=rs.getInt("identificacion");
            this.contraseña=rs.getString("contraseña"); 
            cliente=true;
            */
        } else {
            existe = false;
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Y esta es mi clase `Conexión`

```
public class Conexion {
    private String driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    private String url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=HOTEL";
    private String user="sa";
    private String pass="progra";

    public Conexion() {        
    }

    public Connection Conectar() {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            return (DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void Desconectar(Connection cn) {
        try {
            cn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seguramente, cuando introduces la cédula, estás ingresando algún guión, espacio o letra, como te dicen en la respueta, asegúrate que el parámetro que capturas sea únicamente números.

Answer (score 1):

Esta excepción lanza cuando quieres parsear a entero un caracter no numérico, o bien, **un nulo**, lo cual es tu caso: **java.lang.NumberFormatException: null java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)**  
Asegúrate de que en tu página html o jsp estés utilizando bien el nombre de tu variable Cedula, ya que evidentemente tu servlet no está recibiendo ningún valor.

Answer (score 1):

> [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) Lanzada para indicar que la aplicación ha intentado convertir una
>   cadena a uno de los tipos numéricos, pero la cadena no tiene el
>   formato apropiado.

La exepción [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) se genera en esta linea de código al tratar de convertir mediante `Integer.parseInt()` una cadena que no tiene formato numerico:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Cedula"));
```

Tienes que asegurar el valor de `request.getParameter("Cedula")` sea numerico para evitar el problema.

---

Ejemplos:

Lanzan  [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) :

```
Integer.parseInt(null);
Integer.parseInt("");
Integer.parseInt("a97");
Integer.parseInt("@#$");
```

Conversión correcta:

```
Integer.parseInt("12");
Integer.parseInt("0");
Integer.parseInt("9245");
```

Answer (score 0):

La `Exception` mostrada [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) es clara, el método [parseInt(String valor)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) de la clase [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) espera por parámetro una cadena con un valor numérico , si dicho valor no es numérico lanza la `Exception`

```
Integer.parseInt("") /* Lanza Exception*/
Integer.parseInt("A") /* Lanza Exception*/
Integer.parseInt("123") /* No Lanza Exception*/
```

El posible error es que el parámetro `celula` de `request` tenga un valor nulo o no numérico , Para solucionar esto tendría que validar que la entrada sea valor numérico. Una opción sería usar Expresión regular.`^[1-9]\\d*$`.

```
if(request.getParameter("Cedula")!=null){
  if(request.getParameter("Cedula").matches("^[1-9]\\d*$")){
    System.out.println("Entrada Correcta");
  }
  else
    System.out.println("Entrada Incorrecta");
}
else
    System.out.println("Verificar los Datos");
```

Comment: Un -1 después de mucho. Sería interesante que se añadiera el por qué así mejoro mi respuesta :)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes problemas que al parsear de String a Int. No existe `try{}catch` y por tanto si existe una excepción como puede ser que el valor sea un carácter no numérico o bien un valor *null*, este finalmente te devuelva un error.

Por tanto, lo que debes hacer es adherir un **`try{} catch(){}`** para que este pueda ser ejecutado sin problemas.

A continuación te dejo el codigo:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ServletException, IOException {  
    try{

        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

        int n= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Cedula")); 
        String p=request.getParameter("Contraseña");  


        if(metodos.Validate.checkUser(n, p)){  
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome");  
            rd.forward(request,response);  
        }else{  
            out.print("Sorry username or password error");  
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");  
            rd.include(request,response);  
        }  

    out.close();  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Hubo un error");
    }
}
```

Espero que con esto te aclare las dudas y puedas entender de donde viene tu error. Saludos!

**NOTA:**

Otra forma para que puedas evitar este tipo de errores en caso que estés trabajando con paginas webs, es que antes de enviar el formulario, corrobore un javascript la información a enviar, o bien, dicho input no sea tipo "text", sino "number".

Ej: `<input type="number" id="Cedula" name="Cedula">`

Éxito!