# Tengo un problema en el con el CRUD en JAVA, alguien que me ayude?

Tags: java, web, aplicación-web, crud

Estoy realizando un CRUD con JAVA, voy en la parte de editar datos, pero al momento de crear el código y ejecutarlo me manda el siguiente error **java.lang.NumberFormatException: null** , soy nuevo en todo esto he intentado mirar si tengo algún error en la base de datos y en el código pero no encuentro el error, el código es el siguiente:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>CRUD CON JAVA | SENA</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            try{
                Connection con;
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Escuela","root","");
                
                PreparedStatement ps;
                ResultSet rs;
                
                int id_doc = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
                ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE id_documento"+id_doc);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                
                while(rs.next()){
        %>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="text-center">Editar registro - Escuela</h1>
            <hr>
            <from action="" method="post" class="from-control" style="width: 500px; height: 400px">
                No. Documento:
                <input type="text" readonly="" class="from-control" value="<%=rs.getString("id_documento")%>">
                Nombre:
                <input action="" name="txtNombre" class="from-control" value="<%=rs.getString("Nombre")%>">
                Apellido paterno:
                <input action="" name="txtApUno" class="from-control" value="<%=rs.getString("ap_paterno")%>">
                Apellido materno:
                <input action="" name="txtApDos" class="from-control" value="<%=rs.getString("ap_materno")%>">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                <a href="index.jsp">Regresar</a>
            </from>
            <% } %>      
        </div>
        <% 
            
            String nom, ape1, ape2;
            
            nom = request.getParameter("txtNombre");
            ape1 = request.getParameter("txtApUno");
            ape2 = request.getParameter("txtApDos");
            
            if((nom!=null) && (ape1!=null) && (ape2!=null)){
                
                ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE alumnos SET nombre='"+nom+"',ap_paterno='"+ape1+"',ap_materno='"+ape2+"'WHERE id_documento="+id_doc);
                ps.executeUpdate();
                response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            }
          }catch(Exception e){
           out.print("Tienes el seguiente error: "+e);
          }
           
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

la verdad no se cual sea el problema, si alguien me puede guiar se lo agradecería.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [java.lang.NumberFormatException: null](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63253/java-lang-numberformatexception-null)

Comment: Estás haciendo `Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"))`... pero no es claro de dónde sale o cómo llega ese id y esa instrucción está recibiendo un valor nulo

Comment: Si el valor que refiere @Alfabravo sería este: `<input type="text" readonly="" class="from-control" value="<%=rs.getString("id_documento")%>">` no se está enviando al servidor, porque no le has asignado `name`, prueba a ponerlo así: `<input type="text" name="id" readonly="" class="from-control" value="<%=rs.getString("id_documento")%>">` y dinos si funciona.

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo acabo de probar y no funciona, aún me sale el error, pero muchas gracias por la ayuda, seguiré buscando.

Comment: ¿El NPE te lo indica exactamente en esa línea? ¿Verificaste que el `input` tiene un dato numérico realmente, si espacios en blanco y demás? Otra depuración a hacer es verificar qué datos estás recibiendo en el request... Cuando se recuperan números deberías usar bloques `try / catch`, para evitar que se intente convertir un dato inválido a número y el programa se detenga.

Answer (score 0):

En el primer scriptlet defines la conexión a la bd y luego obtienes un parámetro para hacer la consulta. Para utilizar "request.getParameter" significa que desde otra parte tienes que enviar ese dato para obtenerlo con request. Intenta lo siguiente:

int id_doc = 1;

Supone que vas a actualizar los datos del primer alumno.

y en la consulta:

ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE id_documento"+id_doc);

debes agregar el signo = después de id_documento

Saludos.